# Handling nodejs input while outputting

Tags: node.js, io

I'm trying to make a program in nodejs which can wait for user input while printing other stuff on the screen without messing everything up.

Using the following code:

```
setInterval( function (){
      console.log("just displaying some stuff");
},1000);
process.stdin.on("data", function(char) {
     console.log(char);
});
```

I get the following result:

```
just displaying some stuff
just displaying some stuff
'this is' just displaying some stuff
'in'just displaying some stuff
'put'just displaying some stuff
```

The result i was looking for is something like:

```
just displaying some stuff
just displaying some stuff
just displaying some stuff
just displaying some stuff
just displaying some stuff
'this is input'
```

Any ideas? I couldn't find anything nearly helpful.

Comment: You're sending the input from stdin to the console immediately. What else did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that with ncurses or some other text-based UI library. In Node there's an excellent module called `blessed` that can help you with things like that. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/blessed

It has some nice demos with even more complicated use cases:

[image]

In your case you can make a window that takes the entire screen minus one line and print your text there, while getting input in the second window below that can be one line high or higher if you need.

It will be more complicated than putting a simple `console.log()` but it is certainly possible and don't listen to people who tell you it's not.

Answer (score 5):

Like rsp said, blessed is a great candidate tool for this. Here's an example implementation for you to use.

I've used blessed to create a textbox at the bottom line in the screen. The rest of the screen is the 'body' where your code output will be added. This way, when you type input, your program won't muddle it with output like you've experienced.

To try this, run `npm install blessed --save`, then run this code in node:

```
const blessed = require('blessed');

var screen = blessed.screen();
var body = blessed.box({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  height: '100%-1',
  width: '100%',
  keys: true,
  mouse: true,
  alwaysScroll: true,
  scrollable: true,
  scrollbar: {
    ch: ' ',
    bg: 'red'
  }
});
var inputBar = blessed.textbox({
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  height: 1,
  width: '100%',
  keys: true,
  mouse: true,
  inputOnFocus: true,
  style: {
    fg: 'white',
    bg: 'blue'  // Blue background so you see this is different from body
  }
});

// Add body to blessed screen
screen.append(body);
screen.append(inputBar);

// Close the example on Escape, Q, or Ctrl+C
screen.key(['escape', 'q', 'C-c'], (ch, key) => (process.exit(0)));

// Handle submitting data
inputBar.on('submit', (text) => {
  log(text);
  inputBar.clearValue();
});

// Add text to body (replacement for console.log)
function log(text) {
  body.pushLine(text);
  screen.render();
}


/*
 * Demonstration purposes
 */

// Listen for enter key and focus input then
screen.key('enter', (ch, key) => {
  inputBar.focus();
});

// Log example output
setInterval(() => {
  log("just displaying some stuff");
}, 1000);
```

Key points here are:

- Your code should show output using the `log` function. Think of this as a `console.log` drop-in-replacement. Don't use `console.*` functions anymore, they'll mess up blessed's screen.
- You have to 'focus' the `inputBar` element for it to receive input. You can have it always focused, however, but my demonstration shows listening for an enter key press or click on the blue bar to focus it.
- If you write code that manipulates the screen, remember to run `screen.render()` to render your changes.